# searching with criteria in subArray and get result with nodeJS and NeDb

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, nedb

i'm frustated for two days, because i'am newbie in nodeJS and JSon.
with my bad english, i have a case for searching data in subdata, and put result in browser.
this is my code :

```
var doc = [{
  "name": "yadi",
  "hobby": [{
    "home": "watch news",
    "bed_room": "read comics"
        }, {
    "home": "watch ufc",
    "bed_room": "eat candy"
        }]
},
  "name": "dony",
  "hobby": [{
    "home": "sleep",
    "bed_room": "eat dog food"
        }, {
    "home": "watch disney",
    "bed_room": "breathing"
        }]
}];
var db = new Nedb();db.insert(doc, function(err, newDoc) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(newDoc, null, ' '));
//search data
db.find({
    "name": "yadi"
  }, { 
    "hobby": {
      $elemMatch: {
        "home": "watch news"
      }
    }
  }, function(err, docs) {

  console.log ("RESULT "+JSON.stringify(docs, null, ' '));

})  
})
```

how i can get data with this result?

```
"hobby": [{
    "home": "watch news",
    "bed_room": "read comics"
        }]
```

Comment: what problem are you facing? any error?

Comment: i cannot get data sub array with spesific criteria

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I'm interested.

Comment: @Gilsdav : i'm sorry.. i didn't find solution, migrate neDB to sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. You're basically not missing a lot except for some brackets here and there and the `"_id": 0` in the projection.

```
var doc = [{
    "name": "yadi",
    "hobby": [{
        "home": "watch news",
        "bed_room": "read comics"
    }, {
        "home": "watch ufc",
        "bed_room": "eat candy"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "dony",
    "hobby": [{
        "home": "sleep",
        "bed_room": "eat dog food"
    }, {
        "home": "watch disney",
        "bed_room": "breathing"
    }]
}];

var db = new Nedb();
db.insert(doc, function(err, newDoc) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newDoc, null, ' '));
});

//search data
db.find({
    "name": "yadi"
}, {
    "_id": 0, // exclude _id
    "hobby": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "home": "watch news"
        }
    }
}, function(err, docs) {
    console.log ("RESULT "+JSON.stringify(docs, null, ' '));
});
```